# Run jQuery, reload, rinse and repeat...how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I have the following code;

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href*="profile"]:contains("PETER PAN")').closest('tr').find('.fightActionInnerInner').click();
});
```

How would I run this, then refresh the page (say every 2-3 seconds) and rerun the script. I'm using Greasemonkey, if that helps. Thanks.

Comment: Would you be able to code that into my code above to show me how it works?

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you can reload the page with `window.location.reload()`, `history.go(0)` or even `window.location.href=window.location.href`

The code in document ready function will automatically run again on page reload.

If you want to delay something, you can do this with `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function (){
    //do something
}, yourMillisecondsToWaitUntilStart);
```

For your code it would be:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a[href*="profile"]:contains("PETER PAN")').closest('tr').find('.fightActionInnerInner').click();
        setTimeout(function(){
             window.location.reload();
        }, msToWait
    });
```

Replace `msToWait` with the number of milliseconds you want to delay the page reload.

Comment: Would you be able to code that into my code above to show me how it works?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the setTimeOut function with a window.location reload like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.reload();
}, 2000);
});
```

Here is the fiddle of a working example:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsgdz/)

Answer (score 0):

Read about the [Meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh).

You just place this inside the head tag of your page

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3">
```

However, I suggest you read the whole page, specifically these parts (even if you end up using the javascript way of redirecting which other users have suggested since this text shows some general drawbacks of refreshing every few seconds, no matter what way you do it):

> Use of meta refresh is discouraged by the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C), since unexpected refresh can disorient users.
>
> Drawbacks
>
> Meta refresh tags have some drawbacks:
>
> If a page redirects too quickly (less than 2-3 seconds), using the "Back" button on the <  next page may cause some browsers to move back to the redirecting page, whereupon the > redirect will occur again. This is bad for usability, as this may cause a reader to be "stuck" on the last website.
>   A reader may or may not want to be redirected to a different page, which can lead to user dissatisfaction or raise concerns about security.
>
> Alternatives
>
> For refresh
>
> An alternative method is to provide an interaction device, such as a button, to let the user choose when to refresh the content. Another option is using a technique such as Ajax to update (parts of) the Web site without the need for a complete page refresh, but this would also require that the user enable JavaScript in their browser.

If you don't really need a page refresh, I suggest you use `setTimeout` javascript function, as already mentioned in another answer (except use it to trigger the click, not reload the page) since refreshing the page is a big thing to do for something small (if the click does something small, which I'm guessing it does).

Comment: meta refresh does not really apply in this *Greasemonkey* context.  Not sure it would even parse reliably when injected.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was just a framework or something, didn't know it was a Firefox Add-on and thought whatever kind of framework or something like that it is, meta refresh can probably be added or at least the other comments would be useful. Still, refreshing a page every few seconds to trigger a mouse click might be a bad idea (I doubt whatever site it is that it would ban the user, but that could happen too)